# C# trying to insert rows from datatable to mongoDB, does not see any insert and no errors on execution

Tags: c#

```
public void readSQLDataforImport()
{
    DataTable sourceTable = SqlReadDB(connectionString, TSQL);
    SaveDataTableToCollection(sourceTable);
}

public async void SaveDataTableToCollection(DataTable dt)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://mongodbserver:27017");

    var database = client.GetDatabase("CentralCollection");

    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Emailrecipients");

    List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        var dictionary = dr.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => dr[col.ColumnName]);
        batch.Add(new BsonDocument(dictionary));   
    }

    await collection.InsertManyAsync(batch.AsEnumerable());
}
```

Comment: What is the WriteConcern you are using? Mongo will not report any error unless WriteConcern is set correctly.

Comment: I added the following line, but no message or any error or any insert happening in MongoDB and no error or message reported in C#

Comment: var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("bySQLDBA_Emailrecipients");

                collection.WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern.Acknowledged);

Comment: it worked with following,

Comment: MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://22.3.33.33:27017");
                MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
               
                server.Connect();

Comment: it looks like these is old method and deprecated, is there any new way I can do the same thing ?